# Xamarin Forms Platform Specific Project Cant See Class Library

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to develop a Xamarin forms application and I'm having problems seeing namespaces in an Android class library I've added to the solution. Note, I'm using visual studio 2015 Community Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.

My Xamarin forms application solution contains the following projects.

- **XFormsApp(Portable)**
- **XFormsApp.Android**
- **XFormsApp.IOS**
- **XFormsApp.UWP**
- **MyCoreComsLib** Preexisting PCL containing communications interfaces/abstractions, and cross platform utilities.
- **MyAndroidComsLib** Preexisting Android specific implementations of the communications interfaces. This library references **MyCoreComsLib**. I believe **MyAndroidComsLib** is an "Android Class Library" project.

Right now I'm just trying to get the android implementation of the Xamarin forms app running so I added the following references between projects.

- from **MyAndroidComsLib** to **MyCoreComsLib**
- from **XFormsApp(Portable)** to **MyCoreComsLib**
- from **XFormsApp.Android** to **MyCoreComsLib**
- from **XFormsApp.Android** to **MyAndroidComsLib**

***My Problem:*** When I work in **CrossApp.Android** I can't see any classes or namespaces from **MyCoreComsLib** or **MyAndroidComsLib**. However, when working in **XFormsApp(Portable)** I can access namespaces / classes in **MyCoreComsLib**. I've used the **MyCoreComsLib** and **MyAndroidComsLib** class libraries in android only c# projects so there aren't any issues with the visibility of classes.

I've done the following in an attempt to solve this issue.

- Made sure **MyCoreComsLib**and **MyAndroidComsLib** built in the cross platform app solution.
- Made sure the references to **MyCoreComsLib**and **MyAndroidComsLib** show up in the references list under the **XFormsApp.Android** project.
- Restarted visual studio.
- Created a brand new Xamarin forms app. Added a new Android Class library to the project. Added a reference from the NewFormsApp.Android project to the class library and attempted to access classes in the class library. Note, I wasn't able to see a class an in the new android class library so this leads me to believe this is a limitation with visual studio / Xamarin but I don't understand why this wouldn't be supported.

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug in visual studio 2015 https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57991. I was able to resolve this issue by switching to visual studio 2017.